# user.dir not resolved properly in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am using the `@Value` annotation with Spring Boot, but it seems like it does not completely work as I would expect.

In my `@Configuration` file:

```
@Value("${installationDirectory}")
private File m_installationDirectory;
```

In my `application.properties`:

```
installationDirectory=${user.dir}/install
```

Startup:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
{
    logger.info( "Starting application" );
    logger.info( "Java version: {}", System.getProperty( "java.version" ) );
    logger.info( "Java home   : {}", System.getProperty( "java.home" ) );
    logger.info( "Operation System: {} {} ({})", System.getProperty( "os.name" ), System.getProperty( "os.version" ), System.getProperty( "os.arch" ) );
    logger.info( "Working dir : {}", System.getProperty( "user.dir" ) );

    SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication( Main.class );
    springApplication.setShowBanner( false );
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = springApplication.run( args );
}
```

Output when starting:

```
2014-05-14 09:36:05 INFO [main] Main - Starting application
2014-05-14 09:36:05 INFO [main] Main - Java version: 1.7.0_55
2014-05-14 09:36:05 INFO [main] Main - Java home   : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
2014-05-14 09:36:05 INFO [main] Main - Operation System: Mac OS X 10.9.2 (x86_64)
2014-05-14 09:36:05 INFO [main] Main - Working dir : /Users/wdb/Work/netty-test
2014-05-14 09:36:05 INFO [main] Main - Starting Main on bruk-00007-l.zone2.flir.net with PID 98296 (/Users/wdb/Work/netty-test/flux-server/flux-server-application/target/classes started by wdb)
2014-05-14 09:36:05 DEBUG [main] Main - Running with Spring Boot v1.0.1.RELEASE, Spring v4.0.3.RELEASE
2014-05-14 09:36:08 INFO [main] LoggingToFileMessageRepositoryDecorator - Storing messages in /Users/wdb/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13/compile-server/install/messages
2014-05-14 09:36:08 INFO [main] OnDiskSingleJvmImageRepository - Storing images in folder /Users/wdb/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13/compile-server/install/images
2014-05-14 09:36:08 INFO [main] TrafficDataIntegratorsManagerImpl - Created 3 integrators for 1 sources in 1 ms
2014-05-14 09:36:09 INFO [main] Main - Started Main in 3.928 seconds (JVM running for 4.428)
```

Notice that the system property `user.dir` points to `/Users/wdb/Work/netty-test` if I just print it. However, where the `installationDirectory` value is injected into a Spring bean, the path seems to be `/Users/wdb/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13/compile-server/install/` instead of the expected `/Users/wdb/Work/netty-test/install`

Note that I am running from IntelliJ 13.1.2 with the "Working directory" set to `/Users/wdb/Work/netty-test` in my run configuration.

Comment: Enable debug (or trace) logging to see how `user.dir` is resolved. I suspect that the `user.dir` property is overridden when the server is started and that it points to the directory the app is deployed/read from.

Comment: Debug shows: `Found key 'installationDirectory' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] with type [String] and value '/Users/wdb/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13/compile-server/install'`

Comment: Well yes, but it should also tell you something about the `user.dir` property. Probably whilst loading the `application.properties`.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible to set "user.dir" from within the JVM, so your process is not starting in the directory you expect it to. Maybe someone who uses IDEA can help you find the right settings (Eclipse definitely behaves as you expect out of the box).

Comment: how about setting `IDEA Run Config` to add parameter -`Duser.dir=specificdirectory` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue. I am building with Maven. The `spring-boot-starter-parent` has resource filtering on by default for `application.properties`:

```
<!-- Turn on filtering by default for application properties -->
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/application.yml</include>
            <include>**/application.properties</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/application.yml</exclude>
            <exclude>**/application.properties</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

It seems that `${user.dir}` is also something that Maven will replace. If I looked at the `application.properties` in my `target/classes`, it was indeed replaced.

To fix, I needed to do the following:

First tell Maven that you want [escape filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <escapeString>\</escapeString>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then change the `application.properties` file to:

```
installationDirectory=\${user.dir}/install
```

After this, everything works fine.